# Invalid query param request when new O365 subscription is created

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a webhook subscription for an `event` resource:

`/me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String%20{+propertyIdentifier+}%20Name%20+propertyGuid+' and contains(ep/value, 'value'))`

`propertyIdentifier` and `propertyGuid` are custom values used

Following response is received:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message":
      "Workload resource uri query string is not support. Querystring: %24filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties%2fany(ep%3aep%2fPropertyId+eq+%27String+%7bpropertyIdentifier%7d+Name+propertyGuid+and+contains(ep%2fValue%2c%27value%27))",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2422c28b-41ba-46d8-8ee9-5a28b2d814de",
      "date": "2018-06-08T17:31:07"
    }
  }
}
```

I see that the API only fails intermittently and would like to understand why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `contains` in your `$filter` parameter. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#format-parameter):

> > **Note:** The following `$filter` operators are not supported for Azure AD resources:  `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`. *The `contains` string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources*.

Comment: Based on this documentation ( https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get#parameters) I see the examples have `contains` in the filter param. My use case is similar wherein I create a subscription only on resources that have the single-extended property that contains a specific value.